# Spark add duplicate only when one column is same and other is different

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data like this

```
[
{"uuid":"fdkhflds","key": "A", "id": "1"},
{"uuid":"ieuieiue","key": "A", "id": "2"},
{"uuid":"qwtriqrr","key": "A", "id": "3"},
{"uuid":"dhgfsddd","key": "A", "id": "1"},
{"uuid":"sdjhfdjh","key": "E", "id": "4"}
]
```

I want to add flag in those column where key is same but id is different.

**Expected output:**

```
[
{"uuid":"fdkhflds","key": "A", "id": "1","de_dupe_required": 0},
{"uuid":"ieuieiue","key": "A", "id": "2","de_dupe_required": 1},
{"uuid":"qwtriqrr","key": "A", "id": "3","de_dupe_required": 1},
{"uuid":"dhgfsddd","key": "A", "id": "1","de_dupe_required": 0},
{"uuid":"sdjhfdjh","key": "E", "id": "4","de_dupe_required": 0}
]
```

**Explanation:**

1. Since first and fourth record have same key and id, So no flag is needed
2. Since fifth record has no same key or id, So no flag for this as well
3. Since second and third have the same key, but id is different so flag should be 1

Comment: Your example is bad. What about A with 4? Pls add.

Comment: What about 2 A,3 combi's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with `pyspark.sql.Window` by generating a [`rank()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rank.html) for the keys ordered by the id. Then marking as `de_dupe_required` wherever the `rank()` is not `1`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

window_spec = Window.partitionBy("key").orderBy("id")

df = (df.withColumn("dupe_rank", F.rank().over(window_spec))
      .withColumn("de_dupe_required", F.when(F.col("dupe_rank")==1, F.lit(0))
                  .otherwise(F.lit(1)))
      .drop("dupe_rank")
     )

df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+--------+---+---+----------------+
|    uuid|key| id|de_dupe_required|
+--------+---+---+----------------+
|fdkhflds|  A|  1|               0|
|dhgfsddd|  A|  1|               0|
|ieuieiue|  A|  2|               1|
|qwtriqrr|  A|  3|               1|
|sdjhfdjh|  E|  4|               0|
+--------+---+---+----------------+
```

---

Note this will still work if there are some combinations like having two (A,3) (as noted by @thebluephantom) since we order by `id` hence the rank will be greater than `1` for these rows.

Output for two (A,3):

```
+--------+---+---+----------------+
|    uuid|key| id|de_dupe_required|
+--------+---+---+----------------+
|fdkhflds|  A|  1|               0|
|dhgfsddd|  A|  1|               0|
|ieuieiue|  A|  2|               1|
|qwtriqrr|  A|  3|               1|
|qwtriqrr|  A|  3|               1|
|sdjhfdjh|  E|  4|               0|
+--------+---+---+----------------+
```

Comment: Actually the answer is incorrect, if there are 2 (A,3) for example.

Comment: @thebluephantom, it will work for the two (A,3) case as well, I have updated the answer to show this. Please let me know if I have misunderstood your scenario! Thanks

Comment: I do not think so the A, 3 should show 0.

Comment: @thebluephantom, I think it's best if OP clarifies this point because my interpretation is different then..

Comment: not the end of the world but it is a poorly formulated question

Comment: @viggnah thanks for helping. I just realized the missing use case in the provided data set and your solution is working in that case as well. Thanks for ll the support.

Comment: @thebluephantom appologies for poorly formulated question.

Comment: Well @Innovation in this case you can upvote as my answer is a superset and will also return the same answer. That seems fair as it is also correct.

Comment: I will consider readability over a slightly fast solution. Second solution seems to be very neat and tidy, I had already written the solution like you did, but that was not neat and clean.

Comment: @Innovation that's a subjective statement. If that had prevailed then the solution would not have worked. I think it is elegant enough, but success in your endeavours! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague. This is my solution whereby we consider 2 A,3's being possible, thus not as per 1st answer.

```
%python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
       ("A", 1, "xyz"),
       ("A", 2, "xyz"),
       ("A", 3, "xyz"),
       ("A", 3, "xyz"),
       ("A", 1, "xyz"),
       ("E", 4, "xyz"),
       ("A", 9, "xyz")
    ],
    ["c1", "c2", "c3"]  
)

df2 = df.groupBy("c1", "c2").count().filter(col('count') == 1)
df3 = df2.groupBy("c1").count().filter(col('count') == 1)
df4 = df2.join(df3, df3.c1 ==  df2.c1, "leftanti").select("c1", "c2", lit(1)).toDF("c1", "c2", "ddr") 
dfA = df.select("c1","c2")
dfB = df4.select("c1","c2") 
df5 = dfA.exceptAll(dfB)
res = df4.withColumn("ddr", lit(1)).unionAll(df5.withColumn("ddr", lit(0)))
res.show()
```

returns:

```
+---+---+---+
| c1| c2|ddr|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  2|  1|
|  A|  9|  1|
|  A|  1|  0|
|  A|  1|  0|
|  A|  3|  0|
|  A|  3|  0|
|  E|  4|  0|
+---+---+---+
```

It's about the algorithm, you can do the rest. It needs to be a step-wise approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using count window function.

Using your input data, I've added a new row for `id=3`. AFAIU, in this case the `id=3` should also be marked `0` as there are now 2 occurrences for it.

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('num_key_occurs', func.count('key').over(wd.partitionBy('key'))). \
    withColumn('num_id_occurs_inkey', func.count('id').over(wd.partitionBy('key', 'id'))). \
    withColumn('samekey_diffid', 
               ((func.col('num_key_occurs') > 1) & (func.col('num_id_occurs_inkey') == 1)).cast('int')
               ). \
    show()

# +---+---+--------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
# | id|key|    uuid|num_key_occurs|num_id_occurs_inkey|samekey_diffid|
# +---+---+--------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
# |  4|  E|sdjhfdjh|             1|                  1|             0|
# |  1|  A|fdkhflds|             5|                  2|             0|
# |  1|  A|dhgfsddd|             5|                  2|             0|
# |  2|  A|ieuieiue|             5|                  1|             1|
# |  3|  A|qwtriqrr|             5|                  2|             0|
# |  3|  A|blahbleh|             5|                  2|             0|
# +---+---+--------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Feel free to drop the count columns at the end.